# Are there Bitcoin addresses with an odd number of transactions?

Tags: transactions, address

When I explore the blockchain on blockchain.info, all Bitcoin addresses seem to have an even number of transactions, e.g. [16Zugc8aq9sPkxBYXyYGqJHTizRzT5wTQg](https://blockchain.info/address/16Zugc8aq9sPkxBYXyYGqJHTizRzT5wTQg) has 16 transactions.
I have looked at a lot of other addresses, too, but couldn't find any with an odd number of transactions.

**Can anyone show me a Bitcoin address with an odd number of transactions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, people spend all outputs from one address in one transaction. If only one transaction was received before each spending, it'll lead to an even number of transactions.

You could just look for addresses that collect tips, such as [Comboy's whiskey fund](https://blockchain.info/de/address/1comboyNsev2ubWRbPZpxxNhghLfonzuN) on [Bitcoinity](http://bitcoinity.org/markets). This particular address has been used "unusually": It currently has 379 transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that, normally, people spend their bitcoins soon and/or use several addresses (each one for 1 or few transaction); the following addresses shows an exception, which I, finally, found.

https://blockchain.info/address/126b9vwrfEYH6NehYmUCTjAga4Dg8UocAQ